# Does saying "A indicates B" mean that the speaker has concluded that B is true?

Tags: meaning

If a reporter says something like "there is evidence that indicates the suspect committed the crime" does that mean the reporter concludes that the suspect definitely did it?

I think not, I think a reporter might word it that way deliberately in order to say that it is possible, though unlikely, that the suspect did not do it. The evidence could have been misunderstood or even falsified. Later in the article, the reporter even mentions that there are other possible explanations for the evidence.

But I'm following an argument between someone who says that the reporter is claiming the suspect did it, and someone who disagrees, which got me to thinking about what people think the word "indicates" means.

As an engineer, I am well aware that data can indicate something which turns out not to be true. But do most people understand the word differently?

Comment: I don't think you can infer the reporter's view from the reporter's report that there is evidence that indicates . . . .some evidence may indicate one thing, other evidence may indicate the opposite. The reporter is reporting, and should not be making a judgment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "indicate" has a wide field of meaning.

According to Dictionary.com a primary meaning of "indicate" is

"1. to be a sign of; betoken; evidence; show."

But to provide evidence is not necessarily to prove. "Her pallor indicated her guilt." That sentence does not imply that guilt was proved beyond all reasonable doubt.

Thus, I read "indicate" in this context as intended to lie between "somewhat suggests" and "proves almost conclusively." But, given the word's broad semantic field, different readers will inevitably interpret it differently. And, in fact, the writer may have deliberately intended an ambiguous meaning.

Comment: 'indicate' shares the Latin root 'indico' (speak to) with 'indict'.  (both mean 'to give evidence')

Comment: I read “her pallor indicates her guilt” to mean that the pallor proves she is guilty. That’s partly because “her guilt” apparently exists. If it were “her pallor indicated guilt” it could be followed by “but because she was at work when the house was torched...” When it’s “her pallor indicated her guilt but because she was at work...” it is self-contradictory.

Answer (score -1):

The reporter could have said "... there is evidence that **proves** the suspect committed the crime" if they wanted to say  that the suspect definitely did it. The use of *indicates* is much weaker and leaves open the possibility that the evidence is wrong or misinterpreted or that there is other contradictory evidence.

Also note that the person is referred to as the *suspect* rather than the *perpetrator*. This reflects the fact the the person is only suspected of the crime and that their guilt has not been established.  If and when someone is found guilty, they are no longer a suspect they are the perpetrator/murderer/thief etc.

Comment: A reporter would never say that, except perhaps with allegedly